# Page not displaying CSS and JavaScript behind SSL apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, tomcat, centos7

I have two web app running on two different servers.(198.168.40.23)server-1 and  (198.168.40.20)server-2. server-1 is running a PHP application hosted on an Apache,on a centos7 and )server-2 is running Java spring hosted on Apache Tomcat 7

both of them are behind an Apache SSL Reverse Proxy 
i can to access both(server-1 and server-2) Pages, but i found some portlets' css files could not be loaded behind reverse proxy.

also after i login it returns back to the apache default page.

Why is this happening?

Detail as below

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"

    ProxyPass "/forum" http://198.168.40.23
    ProxyPassReverse "/forum" http://198.168.40.23

    ProxyPass "/voda" http://198.168.40.20:8080/insurance/
    ProxyPassReverse "/voda" http://198.168.40.20:8080/insurance/
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule  proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule  headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule  deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

ssl_access_log for tomcat

```
    [root@]# tail /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
   192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:43:24 +0000] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 200 11398
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:43:24 +0000] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 404 208
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:43:24 +0000] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 404 208
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /voda HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.config.js HTTP/1.1" 404 230
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /lib/ueditorsrc/ueditor.all.js HTTP/1.1" 404 227
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 207
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 230
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/HomeCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 223
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /lib/ueditorsrc/angular-ueditor.js HTTP/1.1" 404 231
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/WebService.js HTTP/1.1" 404 214
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/LoginCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 224
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/DashboardCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 228
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/MyJobCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 224
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/InterestedCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 229
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/RefreshCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 226
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/PolicyCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 225
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/paymentList.js HTTP/1.1" 404 226
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/USSD.js HTTP/1.1" 404 219
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/CustomerListCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 231
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/CustomerEditCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 231
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:53:52 +0000] "GET /js/controller/PaymentListTodayCtrl.js HTTP/1.1" 404 235



 /var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /assets/javascript/jquery.min.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 229
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /assets/javascript/core.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 223
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /styles/elegance/template/forum_fn.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 234
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /styles/elegance/template/ajax.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 230
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /styles/elegance/theme/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 235
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /cron.php?cron_type=cron.task.core.prune_notifications&sid=1ecb7fe43bfcf275d879c20487e23189 HTTP/1.1" 404 206
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /assets/javascript/jquery.min.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 229
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /assets/javascript/core.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 223
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /styles/elegance/template/forum_fn.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 234
192.168.60.150 - - [08/Mar/2018:13:57:54 +0000] "GET /styles/elegance/template/ajax.js?assets_version=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 230
```

What am i missing or leaving out??

Comment: Please provide examples of the URLs that cause problems.

Comment: URLs ??? i dont get it?

Comment: URLs of css files that don‘t load (and corresponding log entries if you can)

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same.